# How to read tiff inside content and based on certain info, copy the file and paste it in respective folder (Python)

Tags: python

I have been stuck for a while when doing this scripts where I need to let the python to read the tiff images file in a folder. Each tiff image inside have certain info that can identify the image (There is Resolution, Binning Mode and IntegrationLevel in the tiff image when open it using notepad++)

By using that 3 info, I need to let python read and store the info for a while with the respective file name and copy to the folder (which the folder need to be same as the image info
(eg: if inside of the tiff image data have Resolution=23000, BinningMode="BackwardCompatible", IntergrationLevel="2", so based on the info, it create a folder if there is no folder based on that info, then it copy the image to that folder.)

I played around with the code by trying these code and no luck with it.
Here is sample file : [Images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1iXD8Yvr4J58_52BF2_timHfJ2Ja242f7?usp=sharing)

```
import os
import shutil
import exifread
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

# Define the input and output directories
input_dir = Path('the origin')
output_dir = Path('output folder')

# Loop through all the files in the input directory
for file in os.listdir(input_dir):
    if file.endswith('.tiff'):
        # Read the image file
        img_path = input_dir / file

        # Get the image metadata using exifread
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as f:
            tags = exifread.process_file(f)
        info = {}
        for tag in tags:
            if tag.startswith('Image '):
                key = tag.split(' ')[1]
                value = tags[tag].values
                info[key] = value

        # Print the keys in the info dictionary
        print(info.keys())

        resolution = int(info['Resolution'])
        binning_mode = info['BinningMode']
        integration_level = float(info['IntegrationLevel'])

        # Create the output directory based on the image data
        output_subdir = output_dir / f"res_{resolution}" / f"bin_{binning_mode}" / f"il_{integration_level}"
        output_subdir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

        # Copy the image file to the output directory
        shutil.copy(img_path, output_subdir / file)
```

I get error which is this

```
> resolution = int(info['Resolution'])
                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'Resolution'
dict_keys(['ImageWidth', 'ImageLength', 'BitsPerSample', 'Compression', 'PhotometricInterpretation', 'ImageDescription', 'StripOffsets', 'SamplesPerPixel', 'RowsPerStrip', 'StripByteCounts', 'XResolution', 'YResolution', 'ResolutionUnit', 'SampleFormat'])
```

When I run this code below to check the metadata, it can run all the things I want

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

# specify the directory path where the images are stored
directory = "image path"

# loop through all the files in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".tiff"):
        # construct the full file path
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)

        # open the image
        image = Image.open(filepath)

        # extracting the exif metadata
        exifdata = image.getexif()

        # looping through all the tags present in exifdata
        for tagid in exifdata:
            # getting the tag name instead of tag id
            tagname = TAGS.get(tagid, tagid)

            # passing the tagid to get its respective value
            value = exifdata.get(tagid)

            # printing the final result
            print(f"{filename} - {tagname}: {value}")
```

These is the few metadata example of the output from the above code

integrationLevel="2"

resolution=23000

binningMode="BackwardCompatible"

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Please fix my code" is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. Please describe what specific problem your script have, and the trouble you have fixing it.

Comment: Oh i forget to add my error, please refresh it and have a look.

Comment: In your error message it shows the dict doesn't have the key `Resolution`, it may be `XResolution` or `YResolution` depend on your need

Comment: @dinhit but when i run another code, it can read thru, i have edited the code, please have a check

Comment: @NekoLim Yes because the other code loop through every key in the dict `getexif()` return and access it directly. They are two different method from two different packages and return different format. Focus on your problem, you are accessing a key that doesn't exists in the dict. If you want the first code work as the second, use the same package and method as the second one